# How to test a cluster of microservices?

Tags: rspec, integration-testing, cluster-computing, microservices, consul

I took a look into [Server Spec](http://serverspec.org/) and it says it clearly:

> Remark: serverspec test suites are meant to be run against a single machine  (or docker container). In other words, you should not try to issue a single rspec command that would harvest and run tests against multiple machines or containers. You need to issue one rspec command for each of them.

So I can do test per-server, which is good for some cases. But the problem is the following: my microservice architecture has a auto-discovery service, so some services are known after querying it. Is there any project to express this? I know I can tool around with ruby (or python if I choose  [testinfra](http://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) or other)

Something integrates with Consul with serverspec or similar will be great, [in 2014 people were looking for this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/consul-tool/PMKN_hop8Ec), does anyone know of any project that tackled this issue?